# How do i save this python code to text file.?

Tags: json

```
# Dependencies
import json
import requests 

# Specify the URL
url = "https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/jokes/programming/ten"

# Make request and store response
r = requests.get(url)

print("Status code:", r.status_code)

response_dict = r.json()



keys = {"setup", "punchline"}
for item in response_dict:
    for key, value in item.items():
          if key in keys:
              print(key, " : ", value)
```

Comment: Sorry, but you just posted a wall of code. Can you explain (by editing the question itself): What is it you're trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you having problems? And please keep in mind, this community is specific to WordPress. So try to answer all these questions in regard to (the latest) WP please.

Answer (score 1):

It's off-topic but if you just want to write the setup and punchline values to a text file you can do something like this:

```
# Dependencies
import json
import requests 

# Specify the URL
url = "https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/jokes/programming/ten"

# Make request and store response
r = requests.get(url)

print("Status code:", r.status_code)

jokes = json.loads(r.text)

with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for joke in jokes:
        f.write("{}:{}\n".format(joke["setup"], joke["punchline"]))
```